# How to run a C++ program inside another C++ program?

Tags: c++, linux, shell

I will sketch the scenario I would like to get working below.

I have one main application.
That application, based on user interactions, can load other applications inside a secure environment/shell. This means these child applications cannot interact with the OS anymore, nor with each other.

The parent program can at any time call functions of these child programs. 
The child program can at any time call functions of these parent programs.

Does anyone know how to implement this in C++? Preferably both parent and child should be written in C++.

The performance of loading the child applications inside the parent application doesn't matter. The only thing that matters is the performance of the communication between child and parent when calling functions of each other.

Comment: `fork()` + `exec()` series of function will help you.

Comment: Is the "child application" already compiled?

Comment: Have you considered using DLLs? What exactly distinguishes a "child application" in your mind? What is a "secure environment" in your definition? What does "child calling parent function" entail?

Comment: Why must the "child application" be a separate program or executable? Why not new objects or data structures which are created according to the user interactions, instead of a separate running program?

Comment: @monad-newb Yeah they are pre-compiled.

Comment: @dmh The user should be able to add and remove child applications at run-time.

Comment: There is no standard C++ way to do this, an answer must be operating system specific.  Please specify what operating system(s) you are targeting.

Comment: @floris A secure environment is an environment where the application cannot interact with the OS anymore and that way not hard the system. 

From my understanding DLLs only work on Windows Systems. The idea is that the child applications can be ran inside any OS (as long as the parent application works for that OS)

Comment: `The parent program can at any time call functions of these child programs. The child program can at any time call functions of these parent programs.` The only way to achieve this is using inter-process communication. This can be done using the fork/exec combo + sockets/pipes/shared memory.

Comment: @floris A child should be able to run a function that is existent inside the parent application. (Maybe trough API?)

Comment: @user1131467 I am targeting Linux / UNIX systems.

Comment: I am thinking of using Dynamic Libraries. Will that provide the functionality as well the security I need? I don't know much about these yet.

Comment: You might want to look into using Qt's QProcess. If Qt is not an option you might want to start here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/interprocess/indexes_reference.html#boost_interprocess_reference.

Comment: This sounds like a "basic" plugin architecture, which can be accomplished quite a few different ways, almost all of them in large part system-specific. Shared libraries (or DLLs in the MS world) are one of the more common methods...

Comment: Sounds like you want a virtual machine of some sort, otherwise reliable sandboxing of precompiled binary apps can be difficult. But probably the best way is to have childs use a scripting language, so they can only do what parent does for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to write your own compiler.

Consider: No normal OS supports what you want. You want both executables to run inside a single process, yet that process may or may not make OS calls depending on some weirdness inside the process which the OS doesn't understand at all.

This is no longer a problem with your custom compiler, as it simply will not create the offending instructions. It's similar to Java and .Net, which also prevent such OS calls outside their control.

Comment: The child process cannot access the OS. They don't have to be executables. They can be separate processes but wouldn't that mean you cannot have any control over them?

Comment: They can't be separate processes. Trivial: you can't call functions across process boundaries.

Comment: ... unless you count RPC mechanisms as function calls (which I guess you could if you were speaking loosely enough)

Answer (score 2):

A portable solution: [Google Native Client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_native_client)

One possible Linux solution:

1. Make AppArmor profile with "hats" (a "hat" is a sandboxing configuration to which the application can switch programmatically with libapparmor),
2. have the main application create a "pipe",
3. have the main application "fork",
4. change into a "hat" corresponding to the child application,
5. "exec" the child application,
6. the main application and the child application communicate via the "pipe" created earlier.

Comment: From my understanding this doesn't prevent the child from interacting with the OS though, which is crucial.

Comment: Binero, having a "secure environment" and "preventing the child from interactive with the OS" aren't one and the same. The latter has little practical value most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a (semi)crossplatform way to do this you can use RPC to call functions in another process. It's going to work on anything that supports the distributed computing environment. It's been around for some time and the msdn documentation states that parts of windows use it for inter process communication so it's probably fast enough. Here's a tutorial on msdn that should get you up and running http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379010.aspx  The bad part is that I haven't been able to find a tutorial about using it on linux.

If you don't want to use RPC or find it too hard to find good documentation on the subject, you can use the standard IPC(Inter Process Communication) mechanisms from unix systems to signal your process that should call a certain function. I'd recommend a message queue because it's very fast and lightweight. You can find a tutorial here: http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node25.html

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with OS restrictions in above answers. However, I found an easy way to solve this problem. I hope it helps and does not have a technical issue. I used Linux OS. Suppose I want to call C++ program B inside another C++ program A. I wrote a perl script (such as PerlScript.pl) that contains a system call to run program B. Then in A, I did a system call like system("perl PerlScript.pl") that ask perl to run B for me.

Comment: Using `system` in such a manner opens very serious vulnerabilities in the code, especially if the person running it can create their own PerlScript.pl file and substitute it in. Also does not support the two processes "calling one another's functions at any time" without extra code in both.